# Remove start of new track from end of audio file

Tags: audio, sox

I've a couple of recordings where at the end of the track there's silence and the start of a new track (fraction). 
I tried to remove the start of the new track from the end of the file.

My command (*nux)

```
sox file_in.mp3 -C 320 file_out.mp3 silence 1 0.75 0.2% -1 0.75 0.2%
```

Preferably keep the silence at the end or just add some new. Any help appreciated

Comment: Could you please provide a link to an example file?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably you can use the *below period* parameter without the *above period*.

A bit of silence can optionally be kept with the `-l` parameter (or you can just use pad with a fixed amount).

**For example:**

**`sox input.mp3 -C 320 output.mp3 silence -l 0 1 0.5 0.5%`**

**Sample input:**

[image: Sample input]

**Result:**

[image]

---

Note, if the beginning of some new tracks has long silence periods inside, it may be tricky - but usually possible - to find appropriate duration and threshold parameters (the general case, apparently, it is not tractable at all by simple processing, one needs a machine learning approach to reliably mark inner periods of silence that belong to a track).

Also, if it is just a *couple* of files, opening an editor e.g. Audacity is the quickest and the best outcome approach.